# I have a project that use 14px in rem, but I want to use 16px in a specify div, is that possible?

Tags: html, css

I'm using Tailwind CSS in a very old project, this project basically have this CSS in global scope

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

There are already a lot of components using `rem` right now.

So my Tailwind CSS relative thing is all kinda broken right now.

So I want to ask if it's possible to use `16px` rem in a specific `<div>`?

Or is it possible to make Tailwind automatically multiply `rem` in `16px` and output static CSS?

Comment: simply override the 14px of the html

Comment: But all my components will be broken because they are already assuming 14px rem.